# VBA Excel .RemoveDuplicates and .Range syntax

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I am trying to remove all of the duplicates in column A of a spreadsheet. This is the only thing that has worked for me so far:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B100").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 1), Header:=xlNo
```

My goal is to be able to select *just the cells with values* from column A, and then remove the duplicates. I have tried this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 1), Header:=xlNo
```

And I get an "invalid procedure call or argument" error. In addition, I also tried:

```
ActiveSheet.range("A1:A100").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 1), Header:=xlNo
```

To just select the first 100 cells of column 'A', and I also got the same error. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: replace `Array(1, 1)` with `1` only.

Comment: One would use the `Array(...` when there are multiple columns on which the criteria for duplicates are found.  when it is only one column then we discard the `Array(...` for the the simple relative column number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to process only the used part of a single column:

```
Sub OnlyColumnA()
    Dim N As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & N).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

***NOTES:***

In this code, **N** defines the row number of the last cell in column **A** with data.  So if the last cell in column **A** with data is cell **A35**, then **N** will have the value *35*.

Thus the expression `Range("A1:A" & N)` is the same as `Range("A1:A35")`, but without the hard-coded *35*.

Comment: Can you break down what is going on with: 'N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row' and also what ("A1:A" & N) means inside the .Range method?

Comment: @electronicaneer  See my ***Notes***

Comment: Ok so when it says ("A1:A" & N) the 'N' is being appended onto the second A almost like it would read "A1:AN" where N is the number of the last cell is column A?

Comment: @electronicaneer  You have nailed it EXACTLY!